# Change tr color when checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have created table like below:

```
<table data-bind="with: choosenDateGoal">                       
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: tblGoals">
      <!-- ko if: status -->
         <tr class="success">
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="this.disabled = 'disabled';" data-bind="checked: status, disable: status, click: $root.UpdateStatus" />
           </td>
          <td>
           <span style="width: 80%" data-bind="text: goals" />
           </td>
           <td>
           <input type="text" style="width: 80%" data-bind="value: notes , event: { blur: $root.UpdateNote}" />
           </td>
           </tr>
          <!-- /ko -->

           </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have an checkbox in every row and when i click on it it should change the row color. 
But not working. here is my script for changing color:

```
self.UpdateColor = function ChangeBackgroundColor() {
    debugger;
    if ($("input[type='checkbox']:checked")) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('success'); ;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use knockout's css binding - see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html
Try binding below and you don't call the ChangeBackgroundColor function

```
  <tr data-bind="css: {success: status()}">
```

Zaik's answer will work, but if you do it the knockout way, you don't need to add any JavaScript eventing code.  This is one of the real benefit's of knockout.

Comment: I would like to use css binding. But i want to change the tr color when checkbox is checked. So how can it be done?

Comment: Pardon my error, I forgot mark my sample as code for SO to correctly display.  I've edited my answer so it shows now.  In my above example, class "success" will display when the expression is true.  Note that "status()" is used.  This "unwraps" the observable to just the value that can be tested.

Comment: Its showing css class effects after page load, But i want to change background color of row when checkbox is clicked.

Comment: status() is showing error 
Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: status is not a function;
Bindings value: css: {success: status()}

Comment: Are you using ko.observable for the property or just binding to an object.  The syntax for observables is to use the () as shown.  If you are just binding to an object, then do not add the ()

Comment: Also, if you are still having problems, can you put together a working, simplified version of your code on jsfiddle so I could see what is happening.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18143/discussion-between-akee-seth-and-photo-tom)